# androidでxls形式のデータを罫線等残したままPDFに変換したい

Tags: android, java, pdf, excel, apache-poi

androidでxls形式のデータを罫線等残したままPDFに変換したいのですが方法が分かりません。
以下のソースのようにでエクセルデータを読み込んで出力する際に元のエクセルのレイアウトを崩さずPDF変換したいのです。
参考になるサイト等ヒントになるようなこと知っている方教えていただけますか

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
try { 
　　InputStream f = this.getAssets().open("seisansyo.xls"); // 既存のExcelファイル名を指定
 　　Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(f);
 f.close(); //ここで入力ストリームを閉じる
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Android/date/" + "workbook2.xls");
　　// 編集したいシート、列、セルを指定
 　　Sheet s =wb.getSheetAt(0);
　　Row r = s.getRow(1);
　　Cell c = r.getCell(1);
　　// この場合B2セルに「あいう」をセット
　　c.setCellValue( "あいう" );
　　c.setCellType( Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING );
　　wb.write(fileOut);
　　fileOut.close();
 } catch (IOException oops) {
　　　Log.e("error", oops.toString());
　　　oops.printStackTrace();
      }
}
```

Comment: 重複候補: [androidのjavaでXLS(エクセルデータ)をPDFに変換したい](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/21916/android%e3%81%aejava%e3%81%a7xls%e3%82%a8%e3%82%af%e3%82%bb%e3%83%ab%e3%83%87%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bf%e3%82%92pdf%e3%81%ab%e5%a4%89%e6%8f%9b%e3%81%97%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84)

Comment: こちらのほうが、目的を達成できていないとはいえ、具体的なコードがあるので残す価値がでる可能性が、比較的高いのではないでしょうか?